# WebView not scrollable if added in row of horizontal flat list in react native android

Tags: react-native

I have a situation where I need to add a webview in horizontal flat list row. When I try to scroll webview horizontally it changes the row of horizontal list but does not allow to scroll webview in react-native android build. But this works on react native iOS build. How to enable scroll of webview on android? Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code -

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <AppQuestionWebView
            style={styles.questionWebView}
            index={this.props.index}
            source={this.props.questionObject.processed_data.question}
            onStartLoad={this.onQuestionStartLoad}
            onEndLoad={this.onQuestionEndLoad}
          />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you solve this?